# How to do browser integration using c++

Tags: qt

I am developing a download manager for Linux and i want to integrate it into firefox, chrome, opera. I am using QT. The download managers like idm, dap integrate into browsers and become somewhat default downloaders for these browsers. Is there any way other than using add-ons like flashgot or download assistant to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a separate mechanism for each application to direct the download into your application, or get the user to copy the link back out, so plugins are your best bet.

Or do something entirely crazy such as monitor all the traffic and snare downloads based off clever filtering, but then you've got the probable side effect of breaking all HTTP requests.

Comment: Actually, developing an add-on for every browser and also keeping in mind that they can get incompatible with new versions is a time consuming and difficult task. There are a lot many browsers for windows like idm and dap which support browser integration. Do they monitor all the traffic. I am using QT, can you give me a hint from where to start with.

Comment: As far as I know DAP actually uses a browser plugin in each one to direct the download back into the main app. IDM I'm not too sure about.